# how does django `makemigrations` work under the hood?

Tags: python, django

My question is: what does calling `manage makemigrations` actually do?

I know it creates migration files, but how? How does it keep track of what changed since last migration? Does it directly compare the current status of the models to the database? Does it keep some hidden files describing the previous status? Which part of the framework code does it call? The documentation says nothing on the subject.

Comment: You may get some idea from here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models are scanned and compared to the versions currently contained in your migration files. It would be a folder inside your application based on the migrations file there a new set of migrations will be written out. As stated by Django official documentation, "Migrations are stored as an on-disk format, referred to here as “migration files”. These files are actually just normal Python files with an agreed-upon object layout, written in a declarative style." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/

Comment: your first sentence, is it based on any docs? it seems to be true by trial and error, but I can't find any mention.

Comment: It is based on the official Django documentation.

Comment: could you point me to that? I'm talking about the first sentence in particular, I can't find anything relevant.